# how can i write a regex in cash to get ips ranging from 162-175 and loopback addresses

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

Hey im trying to write a regex bash expression to get addresses starting with 127 and those randing between 162-175, can anyone correct me where im wrong

`sed -n  's/\([0-9]\{3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/\nip&\n/gp' ips.txt | grep ip | sed 's/ip//'| sort | uniq | cut -d " " -f 1`

Comment: Please create a minimal, complete and reproducible example. State how your solution fails.

Comment: none of the ip addresses mentioned are being filtered

Answer (score 0):

Awk would probably be a better tool for this:

```
awk '{ 
        if ( match($0,/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)) { 
                  split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),map,".");
                  if ( map[1] == 127 || ( map[1] >= 162 && map[1] <= 175 ) ) { 
                            print $0 
                   } 
        } 
      }' file
```

One liner:

```
awk '{ if ( match($0,/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)) { split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),map,".");if ( map[1] == 127 || ( map[1] >= 162 && map[1] <= 175 ) ) { print $0 } } }' file
```

For each line, pattern match for an ip address using awk's match function. Take the first element of this IP address which is placed in the first index of an array map using awk's split function. Check if this map[1] value is equal to 127 or in between 162 and 175. If it meets these conditions, print the line